# Linked accounts to my Gmail, now it has gone crazy - 1000+ invisible unread emails in 4 hours

Tags: email, gmail, imap, pop3, gmail-imap

Help! I linked 2 of my additional emails to my Gmail and now my account has gone crazy. I do not have a good understanding of how server forwarding works, so I just googled it and followed the directions online. I followed the instructions to link accounts using account forwarding. One of them is through Pop3, and the other one is through Gmailify. I also attempted to add a third through yahoo, but yahoo requires a pro membership to set up IMAP email forwarding.

Now, 5 hours later, things have gone crazy. Every 10 seconds my unread email count goes up, despite me not seeing any new emails in any of my accounts. The total space used by my account has gone up by 4%. I now have triple copies of all my email folders. I tried unlinking and relinking an account earlier, and I am unclear if that made the problem worse. I had an enormous amount of unread emails before in my original account, could that be causing the problem? I don't understand where all of these extra emails are, and where they are taking up so much space. What do I do? What have I done?

In addition to this, my phone has now seemed to go nuts also. When I opened my email, my phone downloaded 1000's of old emails. Emails from 2015 now show up right beneath other emails of mine (all from the same account). My phone is rapidly filling up!

I am guessing the problem lies in my lack of understanding about how email servers work. Since this happened, I have done some research about IMAP and POP and things like that. I think I have a basic understanding of how this works. I also think this person - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7481256 - may have had a similar problem. I have no idea how to fix all this however. I'm on a Mac using 10.12.6, and the problem is appearing across multiple browsers and devices.

EDIT: The rate of new unread emails has slowed down significantly, as of a few hours later. I would still like to understand what is happening.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When i used email (gmail) forwarding it forwarded all of my emails to the forward account, this is possibly what is happening to you. The slowing would then be that the number is reaching the end. You can delete or re-unsee the emails in question, it will not affect the emails in the 1st account. The unseen emails have just transferred as visible.The doubling/ tripling of emails could be caused by an option in imap/pop, i remember reading about that trouble but can not find it, sorry it would be in gmail q and a.

Comment: Are you sure this just isn’t a case of Outlook knowing how many unread emails there is on the server and sense you are downloading all emails it has to catch up?

Comment: `I would still like to understand what is happening.` -- At a guess, it simply sounds as if your email accounts is/were syncing. Because one item exists/is marked as read in one client or account, this doesn't mean it exists/will be marked as read in any another.